# How to avoid duplicates without using unique keys in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is a use case where the unique key constraint can be different based on the account. So the duplication restriction cannot be implemented using primary key/unique key constraint.

Assume we have table T1 with columns C1, C2, C3, C4, C5 and we have two accounts A1 and A2. The data of A1 and A2 goes into the same table T1. But to get the unique record for Account A1 we consider C1 and C2 columns and for account A2 we consider C3 and C3. Like wise we can many accounts each having the different set of columns to identify the unique record.

So we have the checks in Java code. But if there are 2 duplicate concurrent requests, the 2 Java threads see that the member doesn't exist and they both insert the record resulting in duplicates. How can I prevent such duplicate inserts?

I can prevent updates by using row level locks or Hibernate's optimistic concurrency. I can think of table level locks to prevent such inserts, but limits the application performance as it also blocks updates.

Comment: Either fix your model, or don't bother with sql. :-(

Comment: You cannot have different primary keys for different columns. As @Strawberry has suggested you need to fix your model. You can have an account id column and only one set of Columns (say C1 & C2). Make a composite key with account id and Columns (may be accid & col1 or acc id & col2 or accid, Col1, Col2

Answer (score -2):

Make the key primary in place of unique